# Joomla : How to filter results of nested/ajax Tag field?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Good day, I am currently using the Tag field of Joomla.

So far so good but I have 3 tag fields in just 1 admin page and all tag fields are just querying all tags in the `#__tags` table.

Is there a way I can filter the tags returned? For example filter by `parent_id` or something like that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I had to do something custom with the tags field recently, and what I did was to clone and rename it and make a new field for my extension that did what i needed.  You put a custom field in the models/fields or model/field folder of your extension.   However I will say that I really like the idea of being able to filter by parent.